# nvme fstrim causing crash on linux, disabling with systemctl doesn't help

Tags: systemd, syslog, trim, fstrim, nvme

I have a Linux (Ubuntu 18, kernel 4.15) desktop booting from an M2 nvme disk.

Once a week, it will crash around midnight. The relevant log file output from /var/log/syslog.* is below:

> Jul 16 00:00:00 rabbitcruncher systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks...
>
> Jul 16 00:00:00 rabbitcruncher kernel: [559644.954267] nvme 0000:41:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0014 address=0x0000000000000000 flags=0x0000]
>
> Jul 16 00:00:00 rabbitcruncher kernel: [559644.975805] nvme nvme0: async event result 00010300
>
> Jul 16 00:00:30 rabbitcruncher kernel: [559675.338834] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0x3, PCI_STATUS=0x1010
>
> Jul 16 00:00:31 rabbitcruncher kernel: [559675.621182] nvme 0000:41:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0014 address=0x0000000000000000 flags=0x0000]
>
> Jul 16 00:01:01 rabbitcruncher kernel: [559706.346300] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0x3, PCI_STATUS=0x1010
>
> Jul 16 00:01:01 rabbitcruncher kernel: [559706.378641] nvme nvme0: Identify namespace failed
>
> Jul 16 13:39:24 rabbitcruncher systemd-fsck[962]: /dev/nvme0n1p1: 12 files, 1186/130812 clusters
>
> Jul 16 13:39:24 rabbitcruncher kernel: [    1.052853] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:41:00.0
>
> Jul 16 13:39:24 rabbitcruncher kernel: [    1.285806]  nvme0n1: p1 p2
>
> Jul 16 13:39:24 rabbitcruncher kernel: [    5.036910] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>
> Jul 16 13:39:24 rabbitcruncher kernel: [    5.318742] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

I understand the "Discard unused blocks" means that Linux is trying to run fstrim. However, I have disabled fstrim using systemctl but it still happens!

> systemctl status fstrim.service
>
> ● fstrim.service - Discard unused blocks
>
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
>
> Active: inactive (dead)

I'm at a loss for what to do to fix this problem. Could anyone offer advice?

Comment: You might need to `systemctl mask fstrim` if `disable` isn't enough. You seem to have a vendor preset that enables it, and I'm not sure if a disable is enough in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Ubuntu** is running inside a `kvm` virtual machine with [`AMD-Vi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD-V#I/O_MMU_virtualization_(AMD-Vi_and_Intel_VT-d)) so it should not be running `fstrim`.

The `fstrim` service runs on a `timer` so as `root`:

```
rm /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-fstrim.timer
systemctl stop fstrim.service fstrim.timer
systemctl disable fstrim.service fstrim.timer
systemctl mask fstrim.service fstrim.timer
```

Comment: Thanks so much... This helps me narrow it down. 

Ubuntu actually is the host OS on the machine and I didn't intend to have any virtual machines installed as far as I know. I looked through and the only thing I could think is that Ubuntu Snaps run a VM called Ubuntu-Core, and it seems that Ubuntu-Core occasionally calls fstrim even though it's a virtual machine.

I uninstalled all Ubuntu Snap and I haven't had this crash since then... kind of crazy, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be related to this [one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1833487#p1833487) describing a crash every time a TRIMming is triggered by `fstrim.timer`.
It seems to be a recent kernel issue that on AMD can be circumvented with `iommu=soft` (I found the prescription [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202665) with not much more details as regards the cause) - as per best practice with NVME SSDs, you can now enable `fstrim.timer` on your M.2 NVME disk back again.

I was bitten by (what I suppose is) the same problem on Intel - I reported it [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1685613) - together with how I sidestepped the problem (`intel_iommu=pt`, which is the Intel equivalent of `iommu=soft`).

Once I made up my mind that the problem involved the IOMMU, I started looking for ways to change its behaviour; that is how I discovered [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.1/html/installation_guide/appe-configuring_a_hypervisor_host_for_pci_passthrough) a Red Hat document regarding best practice for configuring a host for PCI passthrough - a somewhat only marginally related issue - mentioning `intel_iommu=pt` which, for me, solves the problem.

I'm currently not aware of side effects of such setting, if any.

Comment: Thank you for this information. On StackExchange we prefer to have information directly in the answer, just in case the linked pages become unavailable. In this case you might like to provide enough detail here to help someone reading your answer even if the links disappear, but still provide the links for full cross-reference and credit.